# Vuetify data table with external search?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the v-data-table component of vuetify, which you can add a filter bar by default in its properties. This table takes the data from a local json, so far so good.

The problem comes when I have 1 component external to this table, which is a search bar created with (v-form / v-text-field), that bar must do the same function as the search bar of v-data-table .

How can I get the components to communicate with each other and work the same as the one provided by default v-data-table?

If you need example code I will try to make a summary example.

### UPDATE

I have cleaned the code so that it is clearer.

Component A - CardList.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :search="search"
        hide-default-footer
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template v-slot:[`item.datos_paciente.nombre`]="{ item }"
          >{{ item.datos_paciente.nombre }}
          {{ item.datos_paciente.apellidos }}</template
        >
        <template v-slot:[`item.ficha_dental.estado`]="{ item }">
          <v-chip :color="getColor(item.ficha_dental.estado)" dark>
            {{ item.ficha_dental.estado }}
          </v-chip>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:[`item.options`]>
          <v-select v-model="selectDefault" :items="drop"></v-select>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <div class="text-center pt-2">
        <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="pageCount"></v-pagination>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import usersData from "../assets/json/pacientes.json";

export default {
  name: "CardList",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",

      users: usersData,

      selectDefault: "Editar",
      drop: ["Editar", "Finalizar", "Borrar"],

      headers: [
        {
          text: "Nombre y Apellidos",
          value: "datos_paciente.nombre",
        },
        { text: "Clínica", value: "ficha_dental.clinica" },
        {
          text: "Objetivo Tratamiento",
          value: "ficha_dental.acadas_tratamiento",
        },
        { text: "Estado", value: "ficha_dental.estado" },
        { text: "Acciones", value: "options" },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Component B -Search.vue

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field
      outlined
      filled
      append-icon="mdi-magnify"
      color="blue"
      placeholder="Buscar..."
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Search",

  data: () => ({}),
};
</script>
```

View - List.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="mt-5">
      <v-col cols="6">
        <div style="display: flex">
          <div class="mx-4">
            <v-icon color="black">mdi-card-account-details-outline</v-icon>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>Listado de Pacientes</h2>
            <p style="color: grey">Visualizacion de pacientes</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-col>

      <v-col cols="6">
        <Search />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <CardList />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
// Componentes vista principal
import Search from "../components/Search";
import CardList from "../components/CardList";

export default {
  name: "List",

  components: {
    Search,
    CardList,
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `search` prop of `v-data-table` to your `v-text-field`'s `v-model`.

So if you have:

```
<v-text-field v-model="searchInput"/>
```

Where `searchInput` is a local data object, you can bind this object:

```html
<v-data-table :search="searchInput"/>
```

Update: From the code you've added, they are all in different files. Seems like you need to provide a prop to the table component. And emit custom event from text field component to parent component, where the search input will get updated. Here's the correct code:

CardList.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :search="search"
        hide-default-footer
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template v-slot:[`item.datos_paciente.nombre`]="{ item }"
          >{{ item.datos_paciente.nombre }}
          {{ item.datos_paciente.apellidos }}</template
        >
        <template v-slot:[`item.ficha_dental.estado`]="{ item }">
          <v-chip :color="getColor(item.ficha_dental.estado)" dark>
            {{ item.ficha_dental.estado }}
          </v-chip>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:[`item.options`]>
          <v-select v-model="selectDefault" :items="drop"></v-select>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <div class="text-center pt-2">
        <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="pageCount"></v-pagination>
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import usersData from "../assets/json/pacientes.json";

export default {
  name: "CardList",
  props: {
    search: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {

      users: usersData,

      selectDefault: "Editar",
      drop: ["Editar", "Finalizar", "Borrar"],

      headers: [
        {
          text: "Nombre y Apellidos",
          value: "datos_paciente.nombre",
        },
        { text: "Clínica", value: "ficha_dental.clinica" },
        {
          text: "Objetivo Tratamiento",
          value: "ficha_dental.acadas_tratamiento",
        },
        { text: "Estado", value: "ficha_dental.estado" },
        { text: "Acciones", value: "options" },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Search.vue

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field
      outlined
      filled
      append-icon="mdi-magnify"
      color="blue"
      placeholder="Buscar..."
      @input="$emit('updateSearch', $event)"
    ></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Search",

  data: () => ({}),
};
</script>
```

List.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="mt-5">
      <v-col cols="6">
        <div style="display: flex">
          <div class="mx-4">
            <v-icon color="black">mdi-card-account-details-outline</v-icon>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2>Listado de Pacientes</h2>
            <p style="color: grey">Visualizacion de pacientes</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-col>

      <v-col cols="6">
        <Search @updateSearch="searchText = $event"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <CardList :search="searchText"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
// Componentes vista principal
import Search from "../components/Search";
import CardList from "../components/CardList";

export default {
  name: "List",
  data() {
    searchText: '',
  },
  components: {
    Search,
    CardList,
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: But v-text-field is component A and v-data-table is component B, they are not in the same .vue file

I have to relate both components.

Comment: @Code Then I'll need the code for A and B and the main file where you put them both together

Comment: Okay, there you have. Thx @Mythos

Comment: @Code Thanks you should edit your question and add it there, instead of writing a separate answer. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Code check updated answer, see if it works for you

Comment: It's perfect, it works, thank you very much!